# Adding an integer after each printed line from dictonaries

Tags: string, python-3.x, int

I am learning how to program in Python 3 and I am working on a project that lets you buy a ticket to a movie. After that you can see your shopping cart with all the tickets that you have bought.
Now, I want after each printed line to add a integer.
For example: 1. Movie1 , 2. Movie2 , etc..

Here is my code that I use to print the films:

```
    if choice == 3:
    #try:
    print("Daca doresti sa vezi ce filme sunt valabile, scrie exit.")
    bilet = str(input("Ce film doresti sa vizionezi?: ").title())
    pret = films[bilet]["price"]
    cumperi = input("Doresti sa adaugi in cosul de cumparaturi {}$ (y/n)?".format(bilet)).strip().lower()
    if cumperi == "y":
        bani[0] -= pret
        cos.append(bilet)

if choice == 4:
    print (*cos, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an integral variable and increase it's value whenever you perform a task.
example set `count = 0` and when you does a task place this there `count += 1`.